# Ordering Names with Prefixes in Biblatex Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, sorting

This is a question which appears to pop up multiple times, but I am never quite able to get the desired answer from other questions.

I am using `biblatex`+`biber`.
I would like to organise names such as `van der Hofstad` by `H` (not `v`). It appears that I can make this work by simply adding `tex.options: useprefix = false` to the *bibliography data*. I think I can also do this by adding `useprefix = false` as an optional argument to `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`.
My understanding is that the latter would make it a rule for every entry while the former would apply this for just the one entry.

***I am more than happy to decide manually for each entry of this form.***
I don't have many like this and so I'd prefer to just add something to the `.bib` file (I use `Zotero` manager, so this is easy) for the ones which I'd like to do this way.
Other questions/answers/comments point out that having a single rule is very complicated (compare `van` and `Jnr`). So I feel simply deciding manually in these cases is best.

Here comes the catch. I have another name, `El-Baz`, which for the life of me I cannot get to organise by `E`, rather than `B`. I've added/removed the `useprefix` option, put it as `true` or `false`. Nothing I do stops it from being ordered under `B`. I want it under `E`. [*Side note: if one *should* order such Israeli names under `B`, not `E`, then please inform me of this!]

---

I don't know how to do MWE with bibliography data, really.
Here's the best that I can do.

> Suppose we have names `{Charles, El-Baz, van der Hofstad, Smith}`.
> I would like them to appear in this order.
> In particular, `Charles < El-Baz` and `van der Hofstad < Smith`.

Again, this does not---and in fact should not---be a complicated automated system.
Adding something in the style of `tex.options: useprefix = false` is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `sortname` option. Note that you can combine this with the `useprefix` option. With this option you can basically place the entry wherever you like (even in absurd places like in the example below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{foo.bib}
@book{charles,
    author = {El-Baz Charles},
    sortname = {augustinea},
    title = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet},
    year= {2020}}   

@book{hofstad,
    author = {Smith van der Hofstad},
    sortname ={wildea},
    title = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet},
    year= {2020}}   

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\textcite{charles} is ordered after \textcite{augustine} thanks to the \texttt{sortname=augustinea} option

\textcite{hofstad} is ordered after \textcite{wilde} thanks to the \texttt{sortname=wildea} option

\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am finding it quite difficult to follow, though. You have combined the four names into two, which is somewhat confusing. I'm not sure who these `augustinea` and `wildea` people are? I don't see their relevant. It seems like I want to use `sortname = Hofstad` (to sort `van der Hofstad` by `H(ofstad)`, not the `van der` part) and `sortname = El-Baz` (to sort `El-Baz` by `E(l-Baz)` not the `Baz` part)? I can't even get yours to compile---I just get an error: `Missing \begin{document}. \begin{filecontents}[o`. It seems like your answer is almost what I want! `:)`

Comment: `augustinea` is an imaginary person. From the point of view of ordering it is the name that comes after Augustine. Same for `wildea`. Yes, with `sotname=hofstad` it is as if the author were called "Hofstad".

Comment: So what is the benefit of writing `sortname=augustinea`? I certainly don't want sort `van der Hofstad` under `A`...

Comment: It was just an example, to show that you can place the entry wherever you like.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. As I said, your example doesn't compile for me. I'll test it in my set-up tomorrow. Bedtime now! `:P`

Comment: Ok thanks, that does work. Writing `sortname = El-Baz` does not. It still thinks that that's a prefix or something. But just `sortname = El` works fine. Hopefully I won't have others with very similar names!